# Accessing Injected service in foreach - angular2

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I have a component which has a service Injected into it's constructor and I have a map function on array of objects. When I tried access my model inside map function it's returning undefined error.

Code:

```
export class StrategyComponent implements ComponentDefinition{
type = "component";
strategies : any[];

constructor(@Inject(GateDataModel) private gateDataModel){
   //Updatedcode
   EmitterService.get("event_name")
        .subscribe(obj => {
            this.buildStrategies(obj.strategies);
        })
}


buildStrategies(_strategies){
    this.strategies = _strategies;
}

selectStrategy(i){ //Function called on click from template
    this.gateDataModel.strategyId = this.strategies[i].id;
    this.strategies.map(function(_strategy, index){
        this.gateDataModel.strategyId = _strategy.id; //Error Here
        i === index ? _strategy.isSelected = true : _strategy.isSelected = false;
    })
}


}
```

How can I access my model inside map function?

Thanks

Comment: How are you initializing "strategies" property?

Comment: I just updated the code how strategies is initialized

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's this part: "this.gateDataModel.strategyId = ...". Try trapping "this" like so: "var _this = this;" and then call "_this.gateDataModel..."

Comment: in the component event to call `_this`, I have to call it as `this._this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, I'm pretty sure the problem is calling '**this**.gateDataModel.strategyId' inside the call back. `this` cannot be resolved in that scope. You have two options:

1. Trap `this` outside like so:

```
selectStrategy(i){ //Function called on click from template
    this.gateDataModel.strategyId = this.strategies[i].id;
    var _this = this;
    this.strategies.map(function(_strategy, index){
        _this.gateDataModel.strategyId = _strategy.id; //Error Here
        i === index ? _strategy.isSelected = true : _strategy.isSelected = false;
    })
}
```

2. You can use a <s>function pointer</s> arrow function expression  instead:

```
selectStrategy(i){ //Function called on click from template
    this.gateDataModel.strategyId = this.strategies[i].id;
    this.strategies.map((_strategy, index) => {
        this.gateDataModel.strategyId = _strategy.id; //Error Here
        i === index ? _strategy.isSelected = true : _strategy.isSelected = false;
    }) // You might need to check my syntax
}
```